# import allow null data from mysql to elasticsearch

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, elasticsearch

my current website is using mySQL and we're starting to transition to elasticsearch.. so now when I'm inserting data to mySQL, I also need to insert that data into my elasticsearch index using bulk.

some of the fields in the mySQL table is allow null and some has default value so we didn't bother giving a value to some of the fields when inserting it. do I need to include all the allow null fields with appropriate default value when adding data to the elasticsearch so the data structure will stay the same?

Answer (score 1):

Even if you didn't set the values for default fields when inserting into MySQL, the database did it for you and actually persisted these defaults.

So now, when you read data from MySQL in order to index it in Elasticsearch, these default values will be there.

However, in contrast to MySQL or other relational databases, Elasticsearch  doesn't have a concept of default values or allow/disallow null values for some fields. So if you plan to treat it as your primary data store (and not use MySQL at all), you need to implement such logic at application level.

Comment: I see.. I think I've just only understood a little bit more about the concept of elasticsearch. it's a completely new thing for me so it's hard to wrap my head around it.

Comment: you can set a default value in Elasticsearch if it receives a null, see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/null-value.html